# ¿Como regresar valores en radio button en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, radiobutton

realizo una consulta en mi formulario con un radio button (en inserción de datos es correcto).
El problema que tengo es que al realizar la consulta en mi formulario no me devuelve los datos correctos que están insertados en la BD me devuelve vació los radio button cuando tendría que  devolver USUARIO o PROVEEDOR según sea el caso.

[image: Consulta de formulario (regresa radio button vacíos)]

```html
<div class="form-group">
 
 <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name"></label>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-18">
                                
         NOTA: CLASIFICAR SI PERETENECE A <b><u>SUB CATEGORÍA AX <b></u><br /><br />
         <input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="USUARIO"> USUARIO<br>
         <input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="PROVEEDOR"> PROVEEDOR<br>
         <br>                                           
    
        <textarea name="process_3" id="mod_process_3" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="JUSTIFICA LA CLASIFICACCIÓN" disabled></textarea><br>
                                
     </div>
    </div>
                        
                        

 **Este script realiza la función si se selecciono la opción de PROVEEDOR se habilita la casilla de comentarios**  

                           
<script>
 $(function(){
 $(".op").click(function(){
     if($(this).val()=='PROVEEDOR'){
      $("#mod_process_3").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#mod_process_3").focus();
     }else{
       $("#mod_process_3").attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
    })
   })  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que agregar un condicional if-else para validar cuál existe y agregarle el atributo checked. Algo como esto:

```
         <input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="USUARIO" <?php if(isset($variable) && $variable == 'USUARIO'){ echo 'cheked';} else{}?> > USUARIO<br>
         <input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="PROVEEDOR"  <?php if(isset($variable) && $variable == 'PROVEEDOR'){ echo 'cheked';} else{}?>> PROVEEDOR<br>

Esto tomando en cuenta que almacenes los resultados de la consulta al campo categoría de la tabla(supongo) en la base de datos, en una variable.
```

Comment: Hola Angel, gracias por reponder asi es el resultado de la consulta se almacena en mi tabla "tickets" y el campo se llama opcion, ya realice la edicion de mi codigo como lo suguieres pero no me arroja aun lo que necesito y tampoco ningun error.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de un error en la tipografía, es "checked" y no "cheked", vuelve a intentar con esta corrección, seguro funciona, y si aún así no funciona en un comentario abajo te dejo otra forma con la que puedes hacerlo también...

Comment: Está es la segunda en qué ha de funcionar(si hay algún error es que ando desde el móvil): ```<?php if(isset($variable) && $variable  == 'USUARIO'){ echo '<input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="USUARIO" checked> USUARIO <br>'; echo '<input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="PROVEEDOR" > PROVEEDOR <br>'; } else{ echo '<input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="USUARIO" > USUARIO <br>';  echo '<input type="radio" class="op" name="opcion" id="mod_opcion" value="PROVEEDOR"  checked> PROVEEDOR <br>';}?>```

Comment: En la primera opción que me proporcionas continua sin mostrarme el radio button seleccionado, en la segunda me selecciona en todos mis registros aunque estén vacíos  la opción de "PROVEEDOR"

Comment: Recuerda que se está validando el valor de una variable comparándolo con el de una string, por lo que debes asegurarte que el valor almacenado en tu base de datos y que estás trayendo a la variable php en el caso de usuario sea igual que ```'USUARIO'```, sino siempre la condición if te retornará false e irá a else, porque la primera condición no se cumple... Tienes que verificar eso, de pronto los registros guardados en tu en tienen alguna diferencia en escritura